# Problem with Injection a Dao Class with @Inject Annotation

Tags: java, wildfly, cdi

Im new in Java EE 7, i'm working with Java CDI tecnologies but unfortunatyl i've got a problem with cdi injection. I write a Java Class with Generic Type that represent a Dao for selecting and inserting data into database. This is a piece of my code:

```
@Named
@Dependent
public class UserDao<U extends User, Q extends UserQueryParam> extends AbstractUniversityEntityDao<U, Q> implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    public UserDao(Class<U> clazz) {

        super(clazz);
    }
```

This is bean file that is correctly configure:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://jboss.org/schema/cdi/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

I Write a JUnit class test for testing my class; this is a piece of my code:

Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserDaoTest.class);

```
@Inject
private UserDao<User,UserQueryParam> dao;

@Test
    public void findByIdListTest() {
        User user= dao.findByUsernameAndPassword("antonio","antonio");
        assertNotNull(user);
        assertEquals("antonio", user.getUsername());
        assertEquals("antonio", user.getPassword());
    }
```

Unfortunatly when i launch the test i've got this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"university-api.war\".WeldStartService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"university-api.war\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Class<U extends User> with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject public it.university.humaninteraction.dao.UserDao(Class<U extends User>)
  at it.university.humaninteraction.dao.UserDao.<init>(UserDao.java:0)
```

Could someone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Where is your producer for objects of type `Class<U>` and how do you expect them to be created at runtime?

Comment: I understand the problem you are having. CDI cannot create a bean of type `Class<XXX>` by itself, you will be needing a producer, as Smutje writes above. But for this use case injecting the class is unecessary. The concrete DAO implementations know the entity they are handling and can call the super constructor themselves: `super(User.class);`

Comment: ok, it work with super(User.class) thanks